# Spark Streaming - StreamingContext sc not defined error

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, jupyter-notebook

[image: Spark-streaming error]

I am getting above error when trying to run Spark-Streaming from Jupyter. Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: have you defined the spark context "sc" before initialising the streamingcontext ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If not, you need to initialize SparkContext before using it

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext("local", "App Name")
```

Hope this helps!